# How to get the value of javascript variable outside of script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable inside my script tag which i am trying to send to a different javascript file.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#target-group').click(function() {
            var targetGroups = $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-$i").map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            $('#out').append(targetGroups.join(','));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried using `<input type="hidden" name="type" id="out"/>` and use this inside another javascript function. But it does not seem to work.

Comment: You can't use `append()` on an input. Try using `after()` instead.

Comment: all scripts have the same scope, they are not separate

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.val()` over input elements since input elements are void elements. They cannot have anything inside of it,

```
 $('#out').val(targetGroups.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the values then try the following.

```
$('#out').val( $('#out').val() + targetGroups.join(','));
```

Comment: I am not trying to aapend the values, I am trying to access the variable outside of the script tag

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1)  your second element selector have `$` in it. To use any of the meta-characters

```
( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ )
```

as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

2) `.append()` appends the content as html and textbox have value property. You should use `.val()` to set the value to input element:

```
 var targetGroups ='';
 $('#target-group').click(function() {
     targetGroups  = $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-\\$i").map(function() {
             return this.value;
         }).get();
         $('#out').val(targetGroups.join(','));
 });
```

Comment: I still am not able to use targetGroups outside of the script tag.

Comment: check the updated code. defined variable `targetGroups ` as global

Answer (score 0):

You can store that value in local storage.

`localStorage.setItem('value', targetGroups.join(','));`

And you can access it as

`var val = localStorage.getItem('value');`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access your variable from another script, is that correct? You can easily achieve that by making the scope of your variable global. To do that, remove the `var` keyword, which makes your variable local, or, if you want to be more explicit, set it to the `window` object, like that:

```
window.targetGroups = .....
```

Comment: I changed it to window.targetGroups = $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-$i").map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();

                    $('#out').val(window.targetGroups.join(','));

Comment: But I still get Uncaught ReferenceError: targetGroups is not defined when trying to access from different javascript file

Comment: Can you confirm that: 1) the second script is in the same page 2) the second script is loaded AFTER the first one ? Further: could you post the result of  $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-$i").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get(); so that we can check whether it is defined?

Comment: No it's a different javascript file.

Comment: All right, but are both scripts included in the same HTML page?

Comment: No they are two different javascript files.

Comment: I understand that you have two different javascript files. What I need to know is this: do you have an html page that includes your two different javascript files? If not so, can you describe your scenario?